# How can i output my console log into HTML page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I had some methods on ruby, that puts some messages into console.
than I need to output this messages into my html page.
I use form_tag to get an array of this methods and send it to my controller(using jQuery for submit button)

```
<div>
<%= form_tag :testrun, :method => :post, id: 'myForm' do %>
<%= check_box_tag 'testcase[]', :method1 %>
...
<% end %>
<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
</div>
```

This is my HTML page. 
Than i got jQuery script to send my form to controller

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#myBtn').on('click', function() { $('#myForm').submit(); });
          });
      });
   </script>
```

And now I need to redraw that page on click Start button and output console on it. How can I do that.
Sorry, for my english :)

Thats what in my controller

```
class TestRunController  < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
    @test = Case.new
    testcases = params[:testcase]
    testcases.each do |testcase|
      @test.send testcase
    end
  end
end
```

In routes.rb i got

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match '/testrun',    to: 'test_run#show',      via: 'post'
  match '/testrun',    to: 'test_run#new',          via: 'get'
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Test Run') %>
<h1>Test Run</h1>

<p>here will be console.log</p>


<a href="/testrun">New run</a>
```

example of log

```
Started POST "/testrun" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-21 07:12:41 +0300
Processing by TestRunController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"h+zZOjeI4Ou2xiDlr3XOAuOTbNVg2ipS0Y05NoEIq6t5txz/sOjh+Zp4+8ri5TNK7HqDo2RY2mE6QpPtwjnwWg==", "testcase"=>["method1"]}
login successfully
method1 - Success
  Rendering test_run/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered test_run/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9453ms (Views: 31.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So, what you have in view is a set of method names with checkbox against each. User selects one or more method names, they get submitted to some controller action, requested methods get executed and they return something that should be displayed on the form. Right?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh yes. that's exactly what i need

Comment: @JagdeepSingh done that

Comment: @JagdeepSingh i added that, but don't sure it's gonna be useful.

Comment: Are you able to send the method names correctly when you submit the form? Can you show server logs to support that?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh yes. backend works just fine

Comment: @JagdeepSingh added example of log

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that there is no issue in sending the params on form submit to the controller action, you can update your controller and views as below to display the results of methods selected by user:

*test_run_controller.rb*

```
class TestRunController  < ApplicationController
  def show
    @test = Case.new
    @output = params[:testcase].each_with_object({}) do |method_name, o|
                o[method_name] = @test.public_send(method_name)
              end
  end
end
```

*show.html.erb*

```
<h1>Test Run</h1>

<% @output.each do |method_name, result| %>
  <div>
    <p><%= method_name %></p>
    <p><%= result %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Note:** I am using [`public_send`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send) instead of `send` as it prevents you from accidentally calling private methods.

Also refer the docs for [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object).

Comment: thank you for that, but it's not looks like solution for me. that code return just names of the selected methods. and I need to show all console information on a page. i use many of "puts" in my methods.

Comment: Try putting `<%= @output %>` before `@output.each` loop and show what it returns in the view.

Comment: {"method1"=>nil}
method1
all my methods return nil, but in console i got much more information.

Comment: So, your method returns `nil`. The logic to display the result is correct. You need to make sure your method returns something visible.

Comment: What information do you see in console? Are you talking about database queries?